# How do 'meter' and 'rhythm' affect the choice of 'Polymeter' and 'Polyrhythm'?

Tags: terminology, rhythm, meter, polyrhythm

I use chevrons (⟨⟩) to denote the concept behind the word.

> [ [Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/musictheory/comments/44hy4j/eli5_the_definitions_and_logic_of_meter_rhythm/czqgp7v/) :] Meter is the rhythmic structure of the music. For example, a piece of music could be in 4/4 meter, which is a strong-weak-medium-weak pattern of beats. It could be in a compound meter, where the notes are subdivided into three instead of two. It's a general structure that the music fits in. Not all music has this!
>
> Rhythm is the actual timing of the music (relative to the tempo, I guess). For example, a rhythm for one measure of 4/4 might be a half note followed by two eighth notes and a quarter note. You can have many different rhythms within the same meter! This measure may just have a whole note as its rhythm, while that other one might have eight eighth notes.

Why was 'meter' chosen as the root in ⟨[polymeter](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/10508/26407)⟩ and 'rhythm' in ⟨polyrhythm⟩? In other words, why wasn't ⟨polymeter⟩ called polyrhythm instead, and ⟨polyrhythm⟩ polymeter? I understand the choice of ['poly-'](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=poly).

Comment: Two different words were chosen. Does it really matter which is which?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I worry that your quoted source isn't the best; "meter is the rhythmic structure of the music" is not a very good definition. Here, for instance, is a better and more concise definition:

> Meter refers to the grouping of accented and unaccented beats into recurring patterns. (Steven Laitz's *The Complete Musician*)

(Other books/authors, like Lerdahl/Jackendoff in *A Generative Theory of Tonal Music*, Krebs in *Fantasy Pieces*, and Rothstein in *Phrase Rhythm in Tonal Music*, have similar (but more long-winded) definitions.)

Thus, when we talk about polymeter, we're talking about multiple grouping structures. [The SE answer you link](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/10488/polymeter-vs-polyrhythm/10508#10508) displays this nicely in its example of polymeter, because there is a 5-grouped structure playing alongside a 4-grouped one, and the downbeats *of the grouping structures* (that is, the accents) are not aligned.

Meanwhile, the accents in the polyrhythmic example *are* aligned; it's just the rhythm that takes place within these accents that differs.

When viewed in this way, we see that the word roots were chosen correctly.